# What item can only be used in expert-only mode?

Tags: terraria

[Comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Terraria/comments/3bep6m/you_cant_use_expert_mode_items_in_normal_mode/cslmxwt) from discussion [You can't use expert mode items in normal mode.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Terraria/comments/3bep6m/you_cant_use_expert_mode_items_in_normal_mode/).

Cenxx, a developer for Terraria, says here:

> You guys voiced your concerns and we have listened. We will be making
>   some adjustments. There will however be 1 reward that remains
>   exclusive to expert, you will understand why when you see it. :)

What is that one reward that remains exclusive to expert-only mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the Demon Heart. You get it when you open the treasure bag dropped from the Wall of Flesh (it only drops in Expert Mode of course). The reason you can't use it in Normal Mode is because upon consuming the Demon Heart, you get an extra, permanent accessory slot, which is probably too good to allow in Normal Mode.

Comment: Demon Heart works in Normal Mode.  That's odd

Comment: Check if the accessory in the 6th accessory slot works. It probably doesn't.

Comment: It works :)  I get an extra slot to put my balloons in :)

Comment: That's really odd. It probably got glitched.

Answer (score -1):

The Expert-Mode items are drops from Expert-Mode Bosses.
There are more than one of these items. (one for each major boss)

Comment: wat, this didn't answer my question